# Multiple pipelines in python social auth

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-social-auth

I am using python social auth to log users into my django-created website with their facebook/twitter/google + accounts. I would like to have 2 different pipelines for my login and registration buttons. Is that possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not possible to have 2 different pipelines, you can certainly make use of the capabilities to extend the pipeline to consider both the "log in" and "registration" scenarios.

After the default pipeline function **`social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user`**, all subsequent functions have access to the **`is_new`** parameter, which is `False` if the user was already in the database (login scenario) or `True` if it must be created (register scenario). You can use this parameter to customize the logic in your own pipeline functions.

Relevant information here:

- [Extending the Pipeline](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline)